# What is an example for a GCD domain that is neither a UFD (like $\Bbb Z[X]$) nor Bézout (like holomorphic functions on all of $\Bbb C$)?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, unique-factorization-domains

> What is an example for a GCD domain that is neither a UFD (like $\Bbb Z[X]$) nor Bézout (like holomorphic functions on all of $\Bbb C$)?

The confluence of rings being a Bézout domain AND a UFD are all the PIDs. This is an equivalence.
The two examples given are GCD's that are either not Bézout, or not UFD. But there are some GCD's that are neither of the two, I just could not find one easily, apart from:
It seems polynomials over a non-PID Bézout ring would fit the bill, e.g. over the ring of all algebraic intergers (that doesn't satisfy the ACCP), but does anyone have a simpler example?

Comment: I think it would be difficult to have simpler. The only thing you could may  simplify is the choice of your non-PID Bézout domain. You could take $R=\{g\in\mathbb{Q}[X]\mid g(0)\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, so the desired GCD domain would be $S=\{f\in \mathbb{Q}[X,T]\mid f(0,T)\in\mathbb{Z}[T]\}$.

Comment: thanks Greg, a nice idea from the world ov polynomials!